# VS Code, how to display stack trace

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, stack-trace

How to display stack trace in VS Code?

From [display stack trace in VS Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/k--kb--kc--kd--kp--kp--kv--display-stack-backtrace-),  it says,

> When you issue the k, kb, kp, kP, or kv command, a stack trace is displayed in a tabular format. If line loading is enabled, source modules and line numbers are also displayed.

However, I am just not able to make it working. This is what I get when trying with the k, kb, kp, kP, or kv commands:

```
k
Unable to eval expression: "could not find symbol value for k"
Failed to eval expression:  {
 "symbol": "k",
 "scope": {
  "goroutineID": 1,
  "frame": 0
 }
} 

Eval error: could not find symbol value for k
kb
Unable to eval expression: "could not find symbol value for kb"
Failed to eval expression:  {
 "symbol": "kb",
 "scope": {
  "goroutineID": 1,
  "frame": 0
 }
} 

Eval error: could not find symbol value for kb

~. k c
Unable to eval expression: "1:1: illegal character U+007E '~'"
Failed to eval expression:  {
 "symbol": "~. k c",
 "scope": {
  "goroutineID": 1,
  "frame": 0
 }
} 

Eval error: 1:1: illegal character U+007E '~'
```

So, how to display stack trace?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right. So any way to do it with VsCode? I'm debugging Go code BTW.

Comment: I typically just `go run` in the VSCode terminal, then stacktraces are output there

Comment: Oh, I need to print out stack trace when I'm debugging some complicated Go module so that I can know how I ended up there, even when no (crash) stacktraces are printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stacktrace tab is not shown in your case.

To show the panel:

```
  menu->>View->>Run
```

The CALL STACK will be shown on the left side panel by default.